# Can anyone figure out why my carouFredsel doesn't work in Webkit?

Tags: jquery, webkit, caroufredsel

I have used carouFredsel many times without problems. But I have one usage of it which won't work for me in Safari and Chrome, yet works fine in Firefox.

Here is an isolated version of it: http://www.myriadeditions.com/?location_id=305

I have tidied up the HTML (it currently passes validation) yet the slider still fails.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Cheers

EDIT: I've also tried using more recent versions of jQuery and the slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I apply the code after the page is all rendered & loaded, it does work for me. That makes me think that it interferes with either your `window.onload` or your other `document.ready`.

Try to play around with these.

How I found out:

1. I put a breakpoint on your $('slider1').carouFredSel({..})
2. before its execution, in the DOM I changed the ID 'slider1' to 'slider2'
3. I continue execution of JS
4. >> jQuery gives a message that slider1 cannot be found
5. I change the DOM back to 'slider1'
6. I execute code with $('slider1').carouFredSel({..}) (Using your params)

It works then.